# Why does class Money extend Expression in Kent Beck's TDD by Example?

Tags: oop, tdd

I'm studying *TDD by Example* and up so far I'm finding it a great book. But there's a point where he tells us to write:

```
// in class Money:
Expression plus(Money addend) {
    return new Money(amount + addend.amount, currency);
}
```

Which won't build unless we declare:

```
class Money implements Expression {...
```

This doesn't really make sense to me. Author created `Expression` as an interface for `Sum` and `Money` has nothing in common with `Sum`. Later on he adds method `reduce()` in common to both classes, but reduce in Money merely returns `this`.

Making `Money` implement `Expression` is only the path of least effort for removing the error from the `plus()` method, but it fills the code with unnecessary information (it will have to implement reduce() because of this decision) and increases entropy.

I haven't given it much of a thought, but wouldn't it be cleaner to do something such as this?

```
class Money {        
    Money plus(Money addend) {
        return new Money(amount + addend.amount, currency).reduce();
    }
}
// edited this, it previously returned Expression
```

**Edit:**
In the following chapter, author implements a `reduce()` method in another class (named `Bank`), which converts `Money` in between currencies. I still find this to be a weird solution, `Sum` and `Expression` names imply we should have a conversion expression class for this task instead. What the author is likely intending to do is to use recursion to add money in different currencies. Either way, it seems to me that he did some far-ahead planning which seems incompatible with TDD as is presented in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## On planning ahead

TDD doesn't prohibit planning ahead. The process is about getting rapid feedback on your plans instead of wasting days (or weeks) creating elaborate plans, only to see them 'not survive contact with reality' (to paraphrase Helmuth von Moltke). It's okay to think ahead.

Still, Kent Beck reveals in chapter 17 that this isn't his first rodeo:

> "I have programmed money in production at least three times that I can think of. I have used it as an example in print another half-dozen times. I have programmed it live on stage [...] another fifteen times. I coded another three or four times preparing for writing [...] Then, while I was writing this, I thought of using *expression* as a metaphor and the design went in a completely different direction than before."

So, if you think that he's cheating: *yes, he is*. He's open about it, though. I think that the motivation was to present a compelling example. He also writes that it was in part based on early reviews of the book.

## On the API

That doesn't explain why the code looks like it does, but there's a reason for that. It's actually a nice API.

Why can't you write something like `return new Expression(amount + addend.amount, currency).reduce()`?

You can't because the `reduce` method isn't nullary. It takes arguments. You must supply both a bank (which holds the currency conversion rates) and a destination currency.

Keep in mind the problem being solved by the code. People get this wrong all the time, and I think that Kent Beck (inadvertently) fuelled the confusion by naming the example *Money*.

The problem isn't to model *money*, but to model investment *portfolios* in different currencies. If you have a portfolio of 25.000 USD and 10.000 CHF, reducing it to a single currency hides important details. With a portfolio in multiple currencies you diversify risk. Portfolio owners will want to see more than one view of their portfolios. Sometimes, they want to see the portfolio grouped by currency, and at other times they want to see 'the current total worth' of the portfolio presented in a single currency.

The API in the book enables both views.

The reason the underlying 'metaphor' is called an *expression* is that the API is just a specialised expression tree. It turns out fairly well, though, because it's lawful. Restricted to the sub-types presented in the book, [it informally gives rise to a monoid](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/16/money-monoid).

Comment: I think I haven't used good words to explain what I meant: he does far-ahead planning, but only explain his thought process later on. It would be great if he'd explained earlier, as usually beginners in TDD will do far-ahead planning and get lost in all the tasks that come out as a result of this. It's hard to take small steps. But yes, after getting to the end of Part I, the API seems to make much more sense. I tried using expression().reduce() and dropped it, it wouldn't be as nice of an API and it'd be hard to follow examples in the book.

Comment: Still don't get it. Starting with a goal of just being able to add one currency to another,  without being told why, the intuitive example that pops into mind is maybe I want to buy something and I have two bills of differing currencies. I can see no 'expression' abstraction naturally arising without some unstated requirement - like the portfolio.

Without it, the only abstractions needed are money and an exchange institution. It's even enough for a bigger system where you can have accounts in different currencies and need to transfer between these.

Comment: @pafauk. 1. No one claims that this is the only correct solution. 2. As I write in my answer, the goal is *not* to add one currency to another.